# AVAudioPlayer play audio properly in Ipod Touch 4g but not in Ipad, Ipad2, why?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipod-touch

Here is my code:

```
NSError *error;
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[settings alarmAudioName] ofType:@"mp3"];
NSLog(@"%@",path);
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
NSLog(@"%@",[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]);
if (audioPlayer == nil) 
    NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
else
{
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [audioPlayer play];
    NSLog(@"Should have been played");
}
```

NSLog:

```
/var/mobile/Applications/9B5B4E10-A936-4D90-8CBE-17854A0B22F7/SSCA Development.app/Song 1.mp3
file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/9B5B4E10-A936-4D90-8CBE-17854A0B22F7/SSCA%20Development.app/Song%201.mp3
```

Its works correct in Ipod Touch 4g, but not working in Ipad, Ipad2, why?

Thanks the answers,